# Importing CSV with Binary UUID into MySQL Workbench

Tags: python, mysql, csv, mysql-python

I am trying to import a CSV file with 10 million rows of UUIDs, generated in Python, into MySQL Workbench.

Firstly, I created a MySQL table with `binary(16)` column titled `ID`:

```
CREATE TABLE TT (
ID BINARY(16) PRIMARY KEY);
```

Next, I created a 10 million row CSV file in Python using `uuid` library and binary version of UUID:

```
import pandas as pd
import uuid

ID = []

for i in range(10000000):
    ID.append(uuid.uuid4().bytes)

Dict = {'ID':ID}

DF = pd.DataFrame(Dict)

DF.to_csv("Desktop/uuid_table.csv")
```

After setting this I tried to import the CSV file into MySQL Workbench using the Table Data Import Wizard, however nothing changes in original table. The process is finished without errors but it says '0 rows are imported'.

Can someone help me with how to import this CSV into MySQL Workbench? What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: *Can someone help me with this?* With what? I see at least 3 separate tasks...

Comment: @Akina Well, my main issue is how to import that csv into MySQL Workbench. What am I doing wrong? Is this possible doing in MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that your CSV holds a python `bytes` representation of binary data and that is not SQL binary and is not length 16. You could write the hex representation instead. Since this is a single column CSV and there are no characters in the hex alphabet that need to be escaped, you don't need any intermediate like pandas to fix up the data.

```
import uuid

with open("Desktop/uuid_table.csv", "w", newline="") as fileobj:
    fileobj.write("ID\r\n")
    for i in range(10000000):
        fileobj.write(uuid.uuid4().hex + "\r\n")
```

Now you have a single column CSV with no index. I don't use MySQL Workbench but you want its equivalent of

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'Desktop/uuid_table.csv' INTO TABLE `TT` (@var1)
SET ID = UNHEX(@var1)
```

I assume the import wizard lets you pick a format.

Comment: Great thank you. And what if I want to have another column in the table as well as csv, for example `datetime`?

Comment: In that case, the `csv` module or pandas might be the best choice. The csv module is more memory efficient, writing one row at a time but pandas is much more feature rich if you are manipulating the data. I'll add a few examples.